# How to call API view from another View in Django REST framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to call `APIView` from another `APIView`, the code similar to:

**A.views.py**

```py
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response


class A(views.APIView):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       return Response({"message": "class A"})
```

**B.views.py**

```py
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response

from A.views import A

class B(views.APIView):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       http_response = <call_A_APIView>

       return Response({"message": http_response})
```

I have already tried the below code line:

```py
http_response = A.as_view()(request._request)
```

But raise the below exception:

> You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Any idea how to do it in the right way?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that exception. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @aaron Thank you for the response, you are right by saying can't reproduce the same exception, I just re-run Django server and the code executed fine!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not in the code, it's weird that I had only to re-run Django server and the code will be executed as expected, so `B.views.py` will be:

```py
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response

from A.views import A

class B(views.APIView):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       http_response = A.as_view()(request._request)

       return Response(http_response.data)
```

**UPDATE**

it seems that `HttpRequest` AKA `request._request` can't be used multiple times after it has been read by Django Rest Framework `View` parser class that will lead to call `read` method which will change the `_request` object's property `_read_started` to be `True`, and after that if you tried to use `request.data` or `request._request` will raise the exception that shown above because the `request.body` is not accessible anymore due it counts on the value of `_read_started` property, also not to mention that the value of `HttpRequest` has already been converted into `stream` object and stored in the memory.

**SOLUTION**

There are multiple suggestions I found:

1- use `Middleware` to store the `request.body` to use it later in case of need.

2- use a custom parser class that store raw data as property in the `request` object before converting it into `stream` object.

Both of them I found is a little bit complicated, so I changed the way of calling another `APIView` from certain DRF `View`, as shown:

```py
from rest_framework import views, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from A.views import A
from C.views import C

class B(views.APIView):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       # Initialize a new instance of class view 'A'  
       a_view = A()

       # Calling HTTP 'POST' method with DRF request object.
       a_http_response = a_view.post(request)

       if a_http_response.status_code == status.status.HTTP_200_OK:

          # Initialize a new instance of class view 'C'  
          c_view = C()

          # Another calling HTTP 'POST' method with DRF request object.
          c_http_response = c_view.post(request)

          return(c_http_response.data)
       
       else:
          return Response(a_http_response.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think isn't the best practice in Django or DRF to call a view from another. If you want to access the business logic from View A by View B, I recommend you put your business logic in a function outside, in a way you can call that function on both Views A and B.

Said that, **you can call APIView A from by APIView B by invoking the HTTP method *post* from the DRF APIView**, such as `A().post(request)`.

```py
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response


class A(views.APIView):
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return Response({"message": "class A"})


class B(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        http_response = A().post(request)
        return Response({"message": http_response.data})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library to send a `post` to your endpoint:

A.views.py

```py
class A(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({"message": "class A"})
```

B.views.py

```py
import requests


class B(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        r = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/api/a")
        r_data = r.json()
        message = r_data['message']

        data = {
            'status_code': r.status_code,
            'headers': r.headers,
            'message_from_a': message
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Obs: Override `get` on `B` so you can see the message on browsable API.

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately your way only working with GET request and need to provide CSRF token for POST request, the way I explained is more efficient, please read my answer.